# RxJava pull on idle

Tags: rx-java2

Say I have this code:

```
Flowable.generate(e -> {
   e.onNext(1);
   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
})
   .onBackpressureBuffer()
   .window(5)
   .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
   .subscribe(this::consumer);
```

This will push events in groups of 5 and I'll get a group of 5 elements every 10 seconds (since the consumer takes 2s to produce the item).

Is there a way to instead pull in groups of 5? The difference being that it should not wait for the group to fill if the consumer is fast enough to process them. If the consumer takes 1s to process the items, it should process them one by one. If it takes 3 seconds to process the items, then it would get increasing lists of 1, 2, ..., 5 and then be capped at 5 since that's the maximum window.